# How to load cesium globe in firefox

Tags: cesiumjs

I just started testing `Cesium` after I read all the documentation for getting started with it, but I have a problem:

I downloaded the files (`Cesium 1.6 zip`) 
But when I am open file `HelloWorld.html` in Firefox (but also in Chrome) it appears an error:

```
An error occurred while rendering. Rendering has stopped.
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
p@file:///E:/3D/Cesium-1.11/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js:433:19771
et.prototype.createTexture2D@file:///E:/3D/Cesium-1.11/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js:449:19216
H.prototype.update@file:///E:/3D/Cesium-1.11/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js:434:9598
S.prototype.update@file:///E:/3D/Cesium-1.11/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js:452:1283
m.prototype.update@file:///E:/3D/Cesium-1.11/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js:455:27826
vt@file:///E:/3D/Cesium-1.11/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js:458:15315
Ct@file:///E:/3D/Cesium-1.11/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js:458:18817
bt.prototype.render@file:///E:/3D/Cesium-1.11/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js:458:25057
P.prototype.render@file:///E:/3D/Cesium-1.11/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js:464:4096
t@file:///E:/3D/Cesium-1.11/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js:463:23110
```

Please solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to launch it from a local server. Many browsers have different security policies if they load files from file:// or http://

An easy way to [launch a local server is use python](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python) (on linux or cygwin):

```
$ cd /path/to/HelloWorld.html
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Comment: I'm running from python, but it's not getting rid of this error. Which setting in Firefox could be the culprit? Clearly it's being oversensitive. I know it's not a proxy issue because I see the globe in MS Edge.